# Real Time Loop (Clock) using Date Edit in PYQT4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, clock, qtimer

My question is this: How do I use the qtimeEdit in PYQT4 to loop & update, so it is always displaying the current time. Essentially, I would like it to function just like the Windows Taskbar time and date.

For example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4 import phonon
import sys
import os


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8


    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(885, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(885, 450))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(885, 491))
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)        self.timeEdit = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self.splitter)

        self.timeEdit.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.BusyCursor))
        self.timeEdit.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.timeEdit.setWrapping(True)
        self.timeEdit.setFrame(True)
        self.timeEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timeEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.timeEdit.setButtonSymbols(QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.timeEdit.setKeyboardTracking(True)
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("timeEdit"))


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

        Today = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
        self.dateEdit.setDate(Today)

        self.ui.timeEdit = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self)
        self.timeEdit.setDisplayFormat("hh:mm:ss AP")
        self.updateTime()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)



    def updateTime(self):
        current = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.timeEdit.setTime(current.time())




class ControlMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ControlMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self,
                                            "Confirm Exit...",
                                            "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                                            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        event.ignore()

        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()

    def VoluemChanger(self, audioOutput):
        self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audioOutput())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySW = ControlMainWindow()
    mySW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that produces the example.

Comment: try my solution

Comment: I did @eyllanesc. I took screen shots of the error message I was receiving. See Error 1 and Error 2 above. Please and Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyStiefel change self.timeedit to self.ui.timeedit, You use qdesigner and I do not

Comment: @JeremyStiefel show your complete code and I will update my code, or try my code

Comment: @JeremyStiefel show ComtrolMainwindow and UI_mainwindow code, please

Comment: @eyllanesc: Sorry to be a pain. That didn't seem to do the trick. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JeremyStiefel update my solution

Comment: @JeremyStiefel add code on your post, please

Comment: Just did. Sorry, I was having trouble formatting it and reducing the size.

Comment: @JeremyStiefel please, complete your code

Comment: @JeremyStiefel  def VoluemChanger(self, audioOutput):
        self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audioOutput())

Comment: @JeremyStiefel update my solution but remove def VoluemChanger(self, audioOutput): self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audi‌​oOutput())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, implement a timer that will be triggered every second, at which point the time is read and updated.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        # Uncomment if you want to change the language
        # self.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Spanish, QtCore.QLocale.Peru))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit(self)
        self.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat("MMM dd yyyy")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        self.timeEdit = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self)
        self.timeEdit.setDisplayFormat("hh:mm:ss AP")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.timeEdit)
        self.updateTime()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def updateTime(self):
        current = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.dateEdit.setDate(current.date())
        self.timeEdit.setTime(current.time())


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

[image]

if case of  @JeremyStiefel:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(113, 120)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.timeEdit = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("timeEdit"))

        self.timeEdit.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.BusyCursor))
        self.timeEdit.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.timeEdit.setWrapping(True)
        self.timeEdit.setFrame(True)
        self.timeEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timeEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.timeEdit.setButtonSymbols(QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.timeEdit.setKeyboardTracking(True)
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("timeEdit"))


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.timeEdit)
        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateEdit"))

        self.dateEdit.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.BusyCursor))
        self.dateEdit.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.dateEdit.setWrapping(True)
        self.dateEdit.setFrame(True)
        self.dateEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dateEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.dateEdit.setButtonSymbols(QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.dateEdit.setKeyboardTracking(True)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("timeEdit"))


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 113, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))


class ControlMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ControlMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Uncomment if you want to change the language
        # self.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Spanish, QtCore.QLocale.Peru))
        self.ui.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat("MMM dd yyyy")
        self.ui.timeEdit.setDisplayFormat("hh:mm:ss AP")
        self.updateTime()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def updateTime(self):
        current = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.ui.dateEdit.setDate(current.date())
        self.ui.timeEdit.setTime(current.time())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self,
                                            "Confirm Exit...",
                                            "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                                            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ControlMainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Remove

```
def VoluemChanger(self, audioOutput):
    self.ui.volumeSlider.setAudioOutput(self.ui.videoPlayer.audioOutput())
```

Because I did not find the definition of the variables in your code

Comment: Thanks Guy! Ya'll Rock.